# Mocking a call on a public method of an abstract class without subclassing the abstract Class, using mockito prefererably

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am writing an unit testing using JUNIT + Mockito to test a method like :

```
public someObject methodUnderTest(){
  SomeObject obj = SomeAbstractClass.someMethod();

  if(obj!=null){
    obj.someOtherMethod();
  }

  return someThing;
}
```

And I would like to mock the call on `abstract Class "SomeAbstractClass"` mentioned in above code fragment  so i can verify call on "obj" like :

```
verify(SomeAbstractClass).someMethod();
verify(obj).someOtherMethod();
```

I have tried using mockito features like :
Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS
Mockito.RETURNS_MOCKS

but they don't work due to dependencies not available to the SomeAbstractClass.

Note:

1) SomeObject is an Interface.

2) I need a technique to test above code fragment. I am constrained to use the above code fragment and cannot change the code fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: if you write unit test, I guess you still can modify tested method a bit.

Solution:

1. extract static method call to overridable method:

> ```
> public someObject methodUnderTest() {
>     SomeObject obj = getSomeObject();
>
>     if(obj!=null){
>       obj.someOtherMethod();
>     }
>
>     return someThing;
> }
>
> protected SomeObject getSomeObject() {
>     return SomeAbstractClass.someMethod();
> }
> ```

1. then you can use Mockito Spy to partially mock the object you actually test:

> ```
> private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;
>
> @Before
> public void setUp() {
>     classUnderTest= new ClassUnderTest();
>     classUnderTest = Mockito.spy(classUnderTest);
> }
>
> @Test
> public void test() {
>     SomeObject someObject = Mockito.mock(SomeObject.class);
>     when(classUnderTest.getSomeObject()).thenReturn(someObject);
>     classUnderTest.methodUnderTest();
>     verify(someObject).someOtherMethod();
> }
>
> @Test
> public void testNull() {
>     when(classUnderTest.getSomeObject()).thenReturn(null);
>     classUnderTest.methodUnderTest();
>     verify(something);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks miheys for your help. I exactly did the same thing .

Answer (score 2):

Use anonymous classes:

```
public interface SomeObject {
     public Object someOtherMethod();
}

public abstract class SomeAbstractClass {
    abstract SomeObject someMethod();
}

@Test
public void test() {
    SomeAbstractClass target = new SomeAbstractClass() {
        SomeObject someMethod() {
            // some impl
            SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject() {
                public Object someOtherMethod() {
                    // some other impl
                }
            };
            return someObject;
        }
    };

    // now test target
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bohemian , but I forgot to mentioned that SomeObject returned is an Interface as well as "SomeAbstractClass.someMethod()" is a public and static method . Hence I am forced to implement Interface "SomeObject " which I don't want to do as , both "SomeAbstractClass" and "SomeObject "  are part of a 3rd party library which I am using in my web application.

Comment: You can use an anonymous class for an interface (like SomeObject) too - see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PowerMock](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.4.12/apidocs/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html) to mock static and final methods.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem is that your use of CALLS_REAL_METHODS is applying to the entire class, where you really want to mock out specific methods (i.e. make a "partial mock"). You have two options here, one using `thenCallRealMethod`, and one using `CALLS_REAL_METHODS` and then specifically mocking the calls you need:

```
public void testMethodUnderTest_mockSpecificThings() {
    SomeAbstractClass myAbstractClass = Mockito.mock(SomeAbstractClass.class);
    SomeAbstractClass myObject = Mockito.mock(SomeObject.class);
    when(myAbstractClass.someMethod()).thenReturn(foo);
    when(myAbstractClass.methodUnderTest()).thenCallRealMethod();

    myAbstractClass.methodUnderTest();

    verify(myAbstractClass).someMethod();
    verify(myObject).someOtherMethod();
}

public void testMethodUnderTest_makeSpecificRealCalls() {
    SomeAbstractClass myAbstractClass =
        Mockito.mock(SomeAbstractClass.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);
    SomeAbstractClass myObject = Mockito.mock(SomeObject.class);
    // overrides the default answer
    when(myAbstractClass.someMethod()).thenReturn(myObject);

    myAbstractClass.methodUnderTest();

    verify(myAbstractClass).someMethod();
    verify(myObject).someOtherMethod();
}
```

Be forewarned that SomeAbstractClass is never actually instantiated, so if you rely on any behavior in the abstract class constructor, like variable initialization--including inline initialization where the fields are declared--you will need to make those calls explicitly yourself.